# go micro gave me this kind of error while running make build

Tags: go, grpc, go-micro

i had installed micro for learning micro services and go. but when i tried to run make build then i received this kind of weird error. can anyone help me to solve this

```
# github.com/micro/go-micro/v3/runtime/local/process/os
..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\micro\go-micro\v3@v3.0.0-beta\runtime\local\process\os\os_windows.go:13:29: undefined: process.Executable
..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\micro\go-micro\v3@v3.0.0-beta\runtime\local\process\os\os_windows.go:18:29: undefined: process.Executable
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: # github.com/micro/go-micro/v3/runtime/local/process/os
..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\micro\go-micro\v3@v3.0.0-beta\runtime\local\process\os\os_windows.go:13:29: undefined: process.Executable
..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\micro\go-micro\v3@v3.0.0-beta\runtime\local\process\os\os_windows.go:18:29: undefined: process.Executable
make: *** [build] Error 2

Comment: Show how you're fetching all the packages. Try `go get github.com/micro/go-micro/v3` for the latest.

Comment: You've probably either imported them incorrectly or set a wrong goPath. Try using go get PATH or place the path in import(PATH) Also check your goPath settings. Good luck!

Comment: go get github.com/micro/go-micro/v3
go: github.com/micro/go-micro/v3 upgrade => v3.0.0-beta

Comment: path is correct D:\GoProject